# How can I plot a linear and quadratic predictors from a regression model, while also controlling for other variables?

Tags: r, plot, regression, polynomials, quadratic

Here is some data and a model. It consists of a linear and quadratic predictor (a and a2) and a linear control variable (b).

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

d <- as.data.table(cbind(a = rnorm(50), b = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50)))
d$a2 <- (d$a)^2

m <- lm(y ~ a + a2 + b, data = d)
```

I would like to plot the linear and quadratic effects, while also controlling for b.

I have found how to do this if I want only the effects of a and a2:

```
ggplot(d,
       aes(x = a, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ x,
              aes(color = "linear"),
              se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ x + I(x^2),
              aes(color = "quadratic"),
              se = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

But how can I plot this while also controlling for b?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "controlling for b"? What precisely do you want to plot? If you are just trying to make a 2D plot there are only so many continuous variables you can plot at once. But just asking for plotting recommendations is a better fit for [stats.se] where questions about data visualization are on topic. This doesn't seem to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow in it's current form.

Comment: I was under the impression that coding questions went here rather than crossvalidated? I could easily be wrong though. To answer your question, I would like to plot a and a^2 as they exist in a model that also controls for b.

Comment: True, coding questions do go here. You just need to define exactly what you mean by "controls for b". That doesn't sound like a programming problem. That sounds like a data modeling question. It's like asking for a plot that "shows the patterns in my data." That's too general a request. If you are more specific about what you mean then we can help you find the code to solve your problem.

Comment: Ah, I guess it exists somewhere in the middle! I'll post on crossvalidated as well. I'm not sure how else to word it, other than I would like to plot the predictors in model m, and currently, I'm only able to plot a model that goes in the ggplot code that omits predictor b.

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is to plot y and the columns of   `model.matrix(m) %*% diag(coef(m))` except the first column.

Comment: Do you want `stat_function(fun = mean, aes(colour = "adjusted"))` after the two `geom_smooth`? Don't worry about the warning, it works.

Comment: is using an offset along the correct lines: after fitting your model `m` we can get similar using `lm(y ~ a + a2, offset=(coef(m)['b']*b), data = d)` or `lm(y - coef(m)['b']*b ~  a + a2, data=d)`. So using this idea we could create an updated `y` in the ggplot call. i.e. `ggplot(d,  aes(x = a, y = (y-coef(m)['b']*b))) + ...`